# Premiere Pro is not allowing any objects to be dragged to timeline

Tags: premiere

Premiere Pro is not allowing any objects (I have tried titles, video and audio) to the timeline. When I drag it over, it comes up with a closed hand with a crossed circle. I already have media, but now I can't add any more. No layers are locked. I haven't changed any options. Help? Me and my teacher could not figure it out.

Comment: What version of Premiere pro are you using? Are you sure you have created a sequence? Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Where premiere allows you to drop or insert clip depends on on *Source patching* and *Track targeting*. Basically, you can only drop clips into a track that has *Source patching* turned on in the track header.

You also cannot drop clips onto tracks that are *Locked*

[image]

This video explains these features in more detail:

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, but rather a workaround. I created a new sequence and dragged the existing sequence into the new one. I can't say why the other one doesn't work, I have no idea.